# Cordova/Phonegap change www to app

Tags: cordova, yeoman

I'm working on a yeoman generator to help make building phonegap apps easier, but one thing I can't seem to change is phonegaps www folder name to app. I could change yeoman to use www but it would be nice to know if its possible to change cordova to use app (or something else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been sitting here for a while, I ended up continuing to use www folder in my phonegap directory. I wrote a small blog post about this if anyone else is interested.

[Blog Post](http://lucaspaulger.com/javascript/2013/09/25/Mobile-apps-Phonegap-Yeoman/)

Answer (score 2):

I was briefly looking into doing this today, and concluded that it was actually far easier to simply change yeoman.dist to 'www' in my Gruntfile. It doesn't exactly do what you were looking for but it does eliminate the need for duplicate distributable directories.

I wouldn't advise using '/app' as your phonegap/cordova directory, as that code won't be minified/uglified.

Edit: Should have clicked your blog post link prior to posted; that post was great and I actually borrowed some of your Grunt tasks. Cheers!